# Binding JSON to Model C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, model-binding

I have a HttpPost request to my Web API and save the data to my database. The problem is the JSON data is not in a static format, like this:

```
{
"35":{
"FormId":"4",
"DateSubmitted":"2014-04-03 10:45:05",
"UserIp":"127.0.0.1",
"Username":"",
"UserId":"0",
"Lang":"en-GB",
"confirmed":"Yes"
},
"36":{
"FormId":"4",
"DateSubmitted":"2014-04-04 02:18:52",
"UserIp":"127.0.0.1",
"Username":"",
"UserId":"0",
"Lang":"en-GB",
"confirmed":"Yes"
}
}
```

35 and 36 here can be any number and I don't know how to bind this to a Model. 
Anyone can show me a way :(?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have control over how the JSON is formatted?  It looks like you are going more for an array of objects instead of separate named objects correct?

Comment: Yes it's an array of objects that was parsed to JSON. And i do not have control over this. The request is posted from an ajax request in another website

Comment: You can have a wrapper model class that has the array index and the class object. Then you loop over this wrapper model to save the actual data i.e. FormId etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a quick example of how to achieve what i think you are going for using JSON.Net and the dynamic keyword. I stripped out some properties for simplicity sake:

```
[HttpPost]
public void POST(string text)
{
    dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
    foreach (var res in result)
    {
        var ele = new Test();
        ele.ArrayId = int.Parse(res.Name);
        dynamic value = res.Value;
        ele.FormId = int.Parse(value.FormId.Value);
        ele.Ip = value.UserIp.Value;
        //etc.
    }
}
```

and the model class to go along with it:

```
public class Test
{
    public int ArrayId { get; set; }
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public string Ip { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If i'm not wrong Web API using JSON.NET by default. So how can I get that "var text" value from the API action? Sorry but i'm totally new in Web API :D

Comment: No problem. I would think you could change the parameter type of your POST controller to string and you would get the raw JSON value. I will try to edit my answer to include the details.

Comment: thanks it's worked. I get the json raw value and use JSON.NET to deserialize it, then bind to my model :D.